# Iterate Json Data in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to Iterate on this Json Data and add value to the Grid in JavaScript(TypeScript) No Jquery.

```
{"GridHeader":{"Id":"Id","Name":"Full Name","Age":"Age"},"GridData":{"Id":3,"name":"Vu","age":34}}
```

I have the Add function as follows which add header and Data to the Grid:

```
 let header = '{"GridHeader":{"Id":"Id","Name":"Full Name","Age":"Age"},"GridData":{"Id":3,"name":"Vu","age":34}}';
let myheader = JSON.parse(header);


for (var i = 0; ??) {
   ....

    AddRecord(headerdata, i);
}
```

This is where I am adding it to the Grid:

```
function AddRecord(record, n) {
var detail = document.getElementById("detail");
var header = document.getElementById("header");

if (n == 0) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<div style=''>" + record.id + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.name + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.age + "</div>";
}

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.innerHTML = "<div style=''>" + record.id + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.name + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.age + "</div>";
detail.appendChild(newdiv);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to explain in more detail what you mean by "iterate on the data".

```
{
   "GridHeader":{
      "Id":"Id",
      "Name":"Full Name",
      "Age":"Age"
   },
   "GridData":{
      "Id":3,
      "name":"Vu",
      "age":34
   }
}
```

Does not have any Arrays present in it.

If it did have arrays in it, then I'm going to assume you meant something like this:

```
"mydata":{
   "GridHeader":{
      "Id":"Id",
      "Name":"Full Name",
      "Age":"Age"
   },
   "GridData":[
        {
          "Id":3,
          "name":"Vu",
          "age":34
        },
        {
          "Id":2,
          "name":"Vu2",
          "age":33
        },
        {
          "Id":1,
          "name":"Vu1",
          "age":32
        }
   ] 
}
```

If your data looks like that, then you have an array of objects in your grid data, and you would then be able to use something like this:

```
mydata.GridData.forEach(item){
  // DO something with
  // item.Id
  // item.Name
  // item.Age
}
```

Within the loop your code will get called once for each object in the GridData part of your parent and allow you access to each of the 3 properties for each individual item.

However, looking at your data the way it is, then it's just a simple object.

If we imagine you have it in a variable called myData, then you can access it's parts as follows:

```
myData.GridHeader.Id
myData.GridHeader.Name
myData.GridHeader.Age
```

To get the header properties.

```
myData.GridData.Id
myData.GridData.Name
myData.GridData.Age
```

To get at the properties of the one and only non iterable object you have present.

Comment: what is item in mydata.GridData.forEach(item), the Data is exactly like you have mansion.

Comment: It's the current object that your iterating.  You use that as your gateway to access the current element in your loop as my examples clearly show.

Comment: This is actually wrong you can't access it as `myData.GridHeader.Id`. In the forEach structure you can access each element of the array through the `item` which holds the current element's data.

Comment: You know what, your absolutely right, if that's what I was doing.  But if you reread my answer, instead of skipping the detail, and read it carefully, you'll actually see that your the one who's wrong.  Downvote yourself by 1 while your there ;-) then try again.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, your data is actually a javascript object below:

```
var header = {
    "GridHeader":{"Id":"Id","Name":"Full Name","Age":"Age"},
  "GridData":   {"Id":3,"name":"Vu","age":34}
  };
```

And you can loop through it like below:

```
for (var prop in header) {
        console.log("Key:" + prop);
        console.log("Value:" + header[prop]);
    }
```

Please, make it according to your needs. I have give you a clue to iterate it. Thanks.