# How do you iterate through JSON arrays in Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

In Javascript you can iterate through a JSON array by using something like `moves[i].name` in a loop where moves is the JSON array, i is the index, and .name is the value. In typescript, however, when I try to iterate through a JSON array, the same syntax fails.

> Typing `let name:String = totalMap[i].title; throws the error 
>    Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type
>   'JSON' has no index signature.

Is this a difference with Typescript or my code in general?

`totalMap` is initialized as `(<any>map).allAreas` where `map` is a JSON object.

The array is

```
"allAreas" : [{
    "area1": {
        "title": "River",
        "description": "A quiet river deep inside a forest",
        "hazard": "All clear",
        "start": true,
        "north" : "Open field",
        "south" : "none",
        "east" : "none",
        "west" : "none"
    },..]
```

and then it continues on with more areas

Comment: post your array in the qeustion

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON from? What creates `map`?

Comment: Map is created by loading in a JSON file using require, like map = `require('./files.json');`

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400298/iterate-json-data-in-javascript-typescript

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Please post more of your code. Do you have some ambient type definition for JSON?