# How to use KeyValuePipe in components.ts file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, pipe

Is it possible to use KeyValuePipe not in html but in ts file?
If yes, could someone show me how?

This is what I have now but obviously I cannot use the pipe like this.

```
let item of this.entityDetails | keyvalue{
            let properties:PropertyBase<any>[]=[
                new TextboxProperty({
                    key: item.key,
                    label: item.key,
                    value: item.value,
                    required: false,
                }),
                ];
        }
```

Big thanks in advance

Comment: you are just iterating over all the attributes of entityDetails object, right ?

Comment: Yes, entityDetails is any[] array though, so the only way to iterate through it that I know of is to use KeyValuePipe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400298/iterate-json-data-in-javascript-typescript

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. You just have to import it and inject it like any service. You import it from `@angular/common`.

```
import { KeyValuePipe } from "@angular/common";

constructor(private keyValuePipe: KeyValuePipe) {

    const transformed = this.keyValuePipe.transform(this.entityDetails);

    for (let item of transformed) {
      let properties: PropertyBase<any>[] = [
        new TextboxProperty({
          key: item.key,
          label: item.key,
          value: item.value,
          required: false
        })
      ];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom pipe there you can write in ts file 
so you can transform , pass from parent as pipe input and work with your pipe ts file for refernce go here
https://alligator.io/angular/custom-pipes-angular/

Answer (score 0):

yes You Can use pipe in ts file.

```
 constructor(public dataformatpipe: DateFormatPipe){}

ngOnInt(){}

  formatData(date) {
    return this.dataformatpipe.transform(date);
   }
```

html file

```
 <span class="value-data">{{formatData(item.startData)}}</span>
```